# Questions related to medical reimbursment

Tags: income-tax, india, reimbursement

I am aware that an amount of 15,000 rs can be claimed under medical reimbursement in India if you are a salaried employee. I have the following questions related to this process :

1. Let's say that I incur a cost of 15000 rs on a dental surgery in the month of August alone. Does this mean that I can submit this single expense for my medical reimbursement at the end of the financial year?
2. What all medical expenses can be claimed for medical reimbursement. Is a doctor's fee covered under this section or only medicine/medical tests cost can be claimed?
3. If I come under the 30% tax slab and submit bills worth 15000, does this mean I will save 4500 rs?
4. Are there any specific clauses that  I should be aware of under which a medical expense claim can be rejected by my company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say that I incur a cost of 15000 rs on a dental surgery in the month of August alone. Does this mean that I can submit this single expense for my medical reimbursement at the end of the financial year?

Yes

> What all medical expenses can be claimed

Almost everything, Doctors fee, medicines, tests, surgery, etc ofcourse No glasses, contact lens etc. Certain cosmetic items that are also medicinal, can only be submitted with doctors prescription.

> If I come under the 30% tax slab

Yes

> Are there any specific clauses

Check with your company

Edit to answer comment:
15000*30/100 = 4500. The calculation can be more exact as you also pay cess of 3%. Further if your income is above 1 Crore, a surcharge of 10% if total tax is above threshold. So essentially 33% or 1/3 is the tax. Thus 1.5 L under 80 C for ease of calculation would be 50,000. Else it would be 46350.

Comment: Can you please show a calculation of how the savings of 4500 is arrived if one is at 30% tax slab for medical reimbursement of 15000? Similarly if one is investing 1.5L under 80C and comes under the 30% tax slab shall be saving 50K in tax?